# Colocar un encabezado en <table> y que este permanezca fijo al scroll vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery

***me he encontrado con una gran paradoja.***

Ya terminado mi proyecto, he querido mejorarlo corrigiendo algunos detalles como es (entre otros) mantener las celdas de encabezado fijas al momento de hacer scroll vertical en las tablas.

He recurrido al gran **google** en busca de una solución "sencilla", pues considero que el **W3C** desde sus comienzos ha creado las condiciones necesarias para que incluso los navegadores modernos manejen esto sin mayores traumas (sin embargo hasta la fecha todavía ninguno lo maneja).

En mis búsquedas en **google** encontré soluciones realmente impresionantes!! y sin mas comencé a adaptarlas, una y una mas, y otra; y al final ninguna me funciono... porque?. porque tenia yo que adaptar mi código a ellas.

Es por ello que recurro a Uds. para que me ayuden, quisiera una utilidad que me permita hacer lo planteado sin mayores cambios (o al menos los mínimos) mas allá del que significa agregar un `<script src="..."></script>` a mi proyecto.

Es importante mencionar que mi proyecto usa **CSS** y muchas de las rutinas que existen para tal efecto se basan en CSS fuertemente y dañan (o colisionan) con lo que yo ya tengo hecho en mis paginas.

Un requisito indispensable a la solución es que se base exclusivamente en **javascript (o jQuery)** sin tocar el **CSS** de tal forma que no dañe lo que ya he creado.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Aquí les dejo un ejemplo de la tabla a la cual yo quisiera que se mantuviera el encabezado fijo:

```css
.LN { 
  background-color:#3399ff;
  color:#fff;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<table id="TBLineDocument" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN">&nbsp;</th>
   <th class="LN">Producto</th>
   <th class="LN">Descripción</th>
   <th class="LN">Almacen</th>
   <th class="LN">Unidad</th>      
   <th class="LN">Cantidad</th>
   <th class="LN">Valor Bs.</th>
   <th class="LN">Dscto</th>
   <th class="LN">Total Neto</th>
   <th class="LN">Iva</th>
   <th class="LN">Comis</th>
   <th class="LN">Referencia</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">1</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">2</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">3</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">4</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">5</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">6</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">7</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">8</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">9</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">10</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Te recomendaría quitar el exceso de texto, ya que se entiende, y podrías especificar un poco mas las cosas si has intentado algo en concreto.

Comment: @Pedro. El tema es bastante trillado por lo que quise dejar claro la razón del porque lo repito. No existe en Internet un ejemplo que use solamente javascript para lograr lo que quiero. los ejemplos que he intentado son los mismos que estan en Internet pero como te he comentado usan css y me dañan lo que ya he escrito..

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/eNP2N/)

Comment: Gracias @lois6b pero no funciona, si modificas el css y colocas div.body_scroll {
    height: 120px;
    width:40px;
    overflow: auto; 
}
veras como el encabezado se desacopla de la tabla ;-((

Comment: No has considerado cambiar tu código? si las soluciones generan colisión quizás el diseño de tu código sea el problema. Por cierto, tu código está incompleto y tu pregunta también, si quieres solucionar una colisión pq: 1. No mencionas las librerias usadas y 2. No pones el CSS que estás usando?

Comment: @Juan mi proyecto lo estoy desarrollando desde hace 15 años [Sinfonix 2000 for WEB](https://host.ingenix21.com.ve/cgi-bin/sinfonix.pl?^LOGIN.www") (puedes entrar como invitado) y veras que en todas las ventanas hay código donde requiero se aplique el concepto solicitado en la pregunta, es por ello que a estas alturas quisiera un código que se adapte a lo que ya he escrito.

Comment: Perdon el enlace correcto es este: [Sinfonix 2000 for WEB](https://host.ingenix21.com.ve/cgi-bin/sinfonix.pl?^LOGIN.www)

Comment: He publicado un código que hace lo que busco, solo faltan algunos detalles como es fijar los encabezados verticales al scroll horizontal, bienvenida cualquier colaboración bien sea para terminar el código o para mejorar el código ya escrito, saludos

Answer (score 0):

He logrado conseguir lo que buscaba, estoy trabajando en el siguiente código, solo me falta fijar los encabezados verticales, si alguien puede colaborar mucho lo agradeceré

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 FixHeader(".FixHeader");
});

function FixHeader(e) {
 if ($(e).length) {
  $(e).bind("scroll", function() {
   $e = $(this);
   $table  = $e.find("table:first");
   $clone=$e.find("#"+$table.attr("clone"));
   if (!$clone.length) {
    id = new Date().getTime();
    $table.attr("clone", id);
    $clone=$table.clone();
    $clone.attr("id",id);
    $clone.css('position','relative');
    $clone.css("visibility","hidden");
    $e.append($clone);
    $clone=$e.find("#"+$table.attr("clone"));
    $clone.css("width", $clone.innerWidth()+"px");
    $clone.find("thead tr").find("th, td").each(function () {
     if ($(this).is(":visible"))
      $(this).css("width", $(this).innerWidth()+"px");
    });
    $clone.find("tbody, tfoot").each(function () { $(this).html(''); });
    $clone.css("visibility","");
   }
   $clone.offset({top:$table.offset().top+$e.scrollTop(), left:$table.offset().left});
  });
 }
}
```

```css
div.FixHeader {
 width:auto;
 height:180px;
 overflow:auto;
}
.LN { 
  background-color:#3399ff;
  color:#fff;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FixHeader">
<table id="TBLineDocument" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN">&nbsp;</th>
   <th class="LN">Producto</th>
   <th class="LN">Descripción</th>
   <th class="LN">Almacen</th>
   <th class="LN">Unidad</th>      
   <th class="LN">Cantidad</th>
   <th class="LN">Valor Bs.</th>
   <th class="LN">Dscto</th>
   <th class="LN">Total Neto</th>
   <th class="LN">Iva</th>
   <th class="LN">Comis</th>
   <th class="LN">Referencia</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">1</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">2</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">3</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">4</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">5</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">6</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">7</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">8</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">9</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="LN"><a id="LN_Menu_1">10</a></th>
   <td><input  name="LN_codigo_1" size="20" style="width:93px;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_descripcion_1" size="40" style="width:310px; display:inline;" disabled></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Almacen_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="3939">FUERA DE INVENTARIO</option></select></td>
   <td><select name="LN_Unidad_1" size="1" style="width:70px;" disabled><option></option><option value="5452">TRAMO</option></select></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Cantidad_1" size="10" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_valorBs_1" size="12" style="text-align: right;"></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Dscto_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_TotalNeto_1" size="14" style="text-align: right;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_CodIVA_1" size="02" style="text-align: center;" disabled></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Comision_1" size="05" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="05" ></td>
   <td><input  name="LN_Referencia_1" size="13" style="text-align: left; " maxlength="12" disabled></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Este jsFiddle te puede interesar: http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/5KJka/1/